# Synchronizing three comboboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have, 3 comboboxes loaded from database but not binded, with different data but same indexes.
All of them are setup like this:

```
 ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
 ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
 ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycolumn1
 ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = DropDownList
```

I would like to get functionality that when I choose an item in one combo that other two selects item with same index.
Foe start I am very surprised in that event _SelectedIndexChanged is never triggered while I expected to get index from there.

Why is this so and how to get desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your issue partially because you have no posted code for me to help you in your situation. Here is an example I done up for you. This is a quick one, but works; you can actually accomplish this in one procedure, but did this so you could understand the functionality of how this works.

```
    Public Class Form1

'Always give variable a default value'
Private selectedIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myArray() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myArray)
    ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(myArray)
    ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(myArray)
End Sub

'Handles one of your comboboxes'
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Cast this as Integer for selected index and set your variable'
    selectedIndex = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString, Integer)

    'Next lets make sure that we set the other comboboxes to this index'
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
End Sub

'Another one of your comboboxes'
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Cast this as Integer for selected index and set your variable'
    selectedIndex = CType(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString, Integer)

    'Next lets make sure that we set the other comboboxes to this index'
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
End Sub

'Your last combobox'
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Cast this as Integer for selected index and set your variable'
    selectedIndex = CType(ComboBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString, Integer)

    'Next lets make sure that we set the other comboboxes to this index'
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
End Sub
    End Class
```

*** You must add the global variable to the top so it can be used to hold your current comboboxes selected index. You can also ignore the load event as I used this as a reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you MrCoDeXeR. Your code look's like it may give wanted functionality but here is still a problem that _SelectedIndexChanged for my comboboxes are never fired (put a breakpoiont inside handler). What may be reason for that?

Comment: Set it on the first line of your sub not inside. The above code will work I know ; )

Comment: Also clear any code you have if any for your combo boxes and then go to each one of the combo boxes properties and set the drop down style there.

Comment: I accept answer and mark it MrCoDeXeR. Now just to get it working. Actually, In my question is a misake. My comboboxes has "DropDown" style so I can type on it. As new in VBNET i have no idea what can I do that _SelectedIndexChanged event start to work (to be fired)?

Comment: You need to set the break point on the first line of your event to be fired. For example: in code above you can set it on "private sub combo box 3 line" and when u change the index of combo box 3 it will break at that line.

Comment: To be fully sure I make those event handlers by dblclick on each combobox then put yout code inside, place a breakpoints on "selectedIndex = CType(...". Comboboxes are full of data which changes while I'm typing but event is NEVER triggered! If I dont make handlers and copy your code same happens. Totally unexpected situation!

Comment: I have to remove AutoCompleteStringCollection and fill comboboxes with "Items.Add" and events starts to work. ButI havent now sorted lists and suggestion's while typing :)

Comment: You can still have sort. How are you pulling data in; database or are you just filling them in?